# Persistent connection not working, opens new connection on every request

Tags: java, sockets, http, server, persistent-connection

I am trying to implement a persistent http server in java, being new in socket programming, I am unaware of the complications.
But run function of ThreadHandler class, it stucks forever and keep waiting, but at the same time if new request comes a new connection is being made instead of using the previous connection itself (while the initial connection keep waiting for request).
Please suggest the correction 
here is my server code that calls ThreadHandler for threading.

Server code

```
package httpServer;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.*;

public class Server {
    static int countofconnections = 0;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        int port = 14998;

        ServerSocket socketServerSocket = new ServerSocket(port);

        while(true) {
            Socket socketClientSocket = socketServerSocket.accept();
            countofconnections++;


            //Runnable handler = new TinyHttpdSocketHandler(socket);
            ThreadHandler threadHandler = new ThreadHandler(socketClientSocket);
            Thread socketThread = new Thread(threadHandler, "Thread for " + socketClientSocket.toString());
            System.out.println(" connection count is now : " + countofconnections+ " ");
            socketThread.setDaemon(true);
            socketThread.start();               
        }

    }

}
```

ThreadHandler code:

```
package httpServer;


import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.SocketTimeoutException;
//import java.util.ArrayList;

public class ThreadHandler implements Runnable{
    Socket socketClientSocket;
    //ServerSocket socketServerSocket;

    ThreadHandler(Socket socketClientSocket){
        this.socketClientSocket = socketClientSocket;
        //this.socketServerSocket = socketServerSocket;
    }

    @Override
    public void run(){
        boolean alive = false;
        try {
            int count = 0;
            socketClientSocket.setSoTimeout(40000);
            BufferedReader inputFromClient = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socketClientSocket.getInputStream()));
            DataOutputStream outputToClient = new DataOutputStream(socketClientSocket.getOutputStream());


            String messegeFromClient = inputFromClient.readLine();
            System.out.println(messegeFromClient);

            while(messegeFromClient!=null) {
                String requestString = messegeFromClient;
                System.out.println("entering while loop");

                //String in = inputFromClient.readLine();

                while(messegeFromClient!=null && !messegeFromClient.equals("")) {
                    //System.out.printlnln(in);
                    messegeFromClient = inputFromClient.readLine();
                    //System.out.println(messegeFromClient);
                    if(messegeFromClient.startsWith("Connection:")) {
                        String[] connectionTimeString = messegeFromClient.split(" ");
                        if(connectionTimeString[1].equals("keep-alive")) {
                            alive = true;
                            //System.out.println("keep alive found");
                        }
                    }
                }
                count++;
                System.out.println(count);  
                //System.out.printlnln( messegeFromClient);
                String[] tokensStrings = requestString.split(" ");

                if(tokensStrings[0].equals("GET")) {
                    String requestedFilename = tokensStrings[1];
                    if(requestedFilename.startsWith("/")) {
                        requestedFilename = requestedFilename.substring(1);
                        if(requestedFilename.startsWith("~")) {
                            requestedFilename = "/home/suman/users/"+requestedFilename.substring(1);
                        }
                        else {
                            requestedFilename = "/home/suman/public_html/"+requestedFilename;
                        }
                        System.out.println(requestedFilename);
                    }
                    File filetosend = new File(requestedFilename);
                    int filesize = (int) filetosend.length();
                    FileInputStream fileStream = null;
                    boolean fileFound = true;
                    try {
                        fileStream = new FileInputStream(requestedFilename);                    
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        fileFound = false;
                    }

                    if(fileFound) {
                        byte[] fileinByte =new byte[filesize];
                        fileStream.read(fileinByte);
                        outputToClient.writeBytes("HTTP/1.0 200 Document Follows\r\n");
                        outputToClient.writeBytes("Content-Length: "+filesize+"\r\n\r\n");
                        outputToClient.write(fileinByte, 0, filesize);
                    }
                    else {
                        outputToClient.writeBytes("HTTP/1.0 404 Document NOT FOUND\r\n\r\n");
                        outputToClient.writeBytes("404 document not found");

                    }
                    outputToClient.flush();
                    if(alive) {
                        socketClientSocket.setKeepAlive(true);
                        socketClientSocket.setSoTimeout(100000);
                    }
                    else {
                        socketClientSocket.close();
                        System.out.println("closing socket");
                        break;
                    }
                    //socketClientSocket.setSoTimeout(5000);
                }
                System.out.println("waiting");
                messegeFromClient=inputFromClient.readLine();

                while( messegeFromClient == null ) {
                    //this code should be skipped when a new request is made since message from from client will no longer be null in that case
                    messegeFromClient=inputFromClient.readLine();
                }
                if(messegeFromClient==null) {
                    System.out.println("messege is null... I don't think it would be ever executed.");
                }
            }
            socketClientSocket.close();
            System.out.println("closing socket 2");
        } catch (  SocketTimeoutException e) {
            try {
                socketClientSocket.close();
                System.out.println("socket closed");
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
        } catch (IOException ie) {
            ie.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: I did not read through the entire code, but I do no see you sending back any response headers (besides Content-Length) to the client. Persistent connections require the client to send a header `Connection: keep-alive` and the server to respond with the same. It does not seem like you are sending this response headers, so the client may assume that persistent connections are not supported.